# SQL Database Type Problem

Tags: android, sqlite, types

I am trying to put together an SQL database but don't really know how to make it work.  The intention is to have multiple columns, some with integers, some with strings in their cells.  For this app, I want repetitions to be an integer and exercise to be a string.  Here is the relevant parts of the code:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
public static final String KEY_EXERCISE = "exercise";
public static final String KEY_REPS = "repetitions";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + KEY_DATE + " text not null, " 
    + KEY_EXERCISE + " text not null, "
    + KEY_REPS + " int not null, "

public long createExercise(String exercise, int reps) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EXERCISE, exercise);
    initialValues.put(KEY_REPS, reps);

return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

I put data in this table using test strings.  Then I try to pull the data with the following query:

```
public Cursor graphQuery(String exercise, String workout) {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_DATE, KEY_REPS}, null, null,    
        null, null, null);
```

From there I try to put the data into a number array but it gives me an error.  It tells me to put KEY_REPS as a number when I declared it.  But if I declare KEY_REPS as a number it doesn't let me build my databes.

```
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.graphQuery(currentexercise, currentworkout);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
Number[] reps = new Number[]{workoutDbAdapter.KEY_REPS};  //error here
```

I feel like I am missing a key part in how to create my database.  Can anyone help?

Code from book I am trying to follow (except using integers) (from comment on first answer)

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor remindersCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
    startManagingCursor(remindersCursor);
// Create an array to specify the fields we want (only the TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};
```

That being said, if someone knows of a good website that teaches SQLite as it applies to Android that would be awesome. The only ones I have been able to find are generic SQL sites and they aren't very helpful.

Comment: For this and any questions you ask: Please copy and paste the error messages *exactly* as they appeared. Simply describing the error message is not nearly as useful as pasting it in. Likewise with the code -- I'm not sure if `createExercise` is shown as you defined it, because `date` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.graphQuery(currentexercise, currentworkout);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
Number[] reps = new Number[]{WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_REPS};  //error here
```

This code here doesn't do what (I think) you want it to.  You need to iterate over the cursor and get the data from there.  I'm pretty sure, if you followed the Android sample code for using databases that WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_REPS is a string constant that holds reps column name.

Try doing something like this:

```
List<Number> allReps = new ArrayList<Number>();
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.graphQuery(currentexercise, currentworkout);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    int reps = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(mDbHelper.KEY_REPS));
    allReps.add(reps);
}
Number[] repsArray = allReps.toArray(new Number[]{});
// do stuff with repsArray and don't forget to close cursor
```

Comment: I am following an example from a book that I built.  Their code works but it is using strings, I am trying to use integers.
New code is pasted at bottom of question

Comment: Not having the book or the rest of the code, I'm guessing they're building a String array of column names to pass into another query.  Keep following the sample, but replace: `Number[] reps = new Number[]{KEY_REPS};` with `String[] repsCol = new String[]{KEY_REPS};`

Comment: The problem is that I need a Number array to use in my next method call.  And I can't figure out a simple way to convert a String array to a number array so I was trying to make the database column Integers but am failing at that as well.  (I originally had strings and it worked).  Oooh....does a SQL database store everything as a string?

Comment: The column contains integers.  My code example shows you how to get the contents of the database out.  What are you trying to do next?  Passing a String (which `workoutDbAdapter.KEY_REPS` is) as an initializer to a new Number array is incorrect regardless of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Right, I initially had 'String reps = new String[]{WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_REPS}' and that worked.  I was hoping for a shorter way to convert everything but it appears that using something like your code (or similar) is probably my only option.

I have to convert it into a Number[] because that is what is required in the method I am trying to use (imported from another library so I can't change it).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the required method expect to achieve with a Number array containing `{"repetitions"}`?

Comment: The "repetitions" column contains a count of reps for each exercise (8,9,10 etc).  I am trying to pull all the values for reps for each row (exercise) into an array.  Then I pass that Number[] into a method that is going to graph it over time.

Comment: Yeah that code works.  I'm going to have to go through it and try to understand what is happening though.  There is one problem.  It misses the first number and outputs an array of length 4 instead of what the cursor brings back from the query (5).  I just ran it through the debugger and it starts at position 0 before the loop.  Then as soon as it enters the loop its at position 1 (skips 0).  I think it has to do with the cursor.movetonext

Comment: Fixed it by adding cursor.move(-1) prior to the while loop.  Now when it enters the loop its at -1 and then as soon as the loop starts its at 0.

Comment: I copied your code exactly as it is.  The only thing that may affect it:  In my query method I have a statement cursor.moveToFirst().  Could that be effecting it?

Comment: Yes, that would move the cursor to the first position, and if you don't read from that position before calling cursor.moveToNext() it'll skip that entry entirely.

Comment: But if you don't call cursor.moveToFirst() isn't the cursor at the end of the query?  So when you call cursor.moveToNext() it won't move to anything because it will be at the end?